# Using Activity or Fragment Shared Element Transitions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-transitions

I'm trying to get a transitional effect working by clicking a grid photo in a ViewPager fragment. The effect looks like this:

[image: THIS].

My code launches a new activity hosting a detail fragment so I'm looking at a combination of a fragment inside a viewPager container that launches a new activity with its own fragment container, displaying the large image.

It looks like this:

1. [HomeActivity - ViewPager container]
2. [RecentFragment - RecyclerAdapter/GridLayout)] > [click grid image]
3. [Launch PhotoViewActivity - new container]
4. [Add PhotoViewFragment to container]

I've looked a few guides online and  they describe the way to achieve this using either Activities or Fragments. Not a combination of both. Where would the transition be applied?

**RecentFragment:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.large_photo), url);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This launches the activity in a new container which hosts the PhotoViewFragment (Fullscreen image)

**PhotoViewActivity**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photoview);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.photo_large_view);
    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new PhotoViewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.photoview_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

**PhotoViewFragment:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    mUrl = bundle.getString(getContext().getString(R.string.large_photo));
}
```